# Using PHP Virtual() to include another PHP file fails

Tags: php, virtual

I have HTML and PHP files that include the "header" HTML for my website. In HTML files I include this header using 
`<!--#include virtual="/top.ssi" -->`.
top.ssi in turn includes other files:
`<!--#include virtual="/navbar.ssi" -->`
`<!--#include virtual="/advertising/slider_advertising.ssi" -->`
and slider_advertising.ssi includes:
`<!--#include virtual="/advertising/advertising.php" -->`
This is the critical file as it prepares advertising data for display.
All the above works great when run from HTML files.

Now I have some PHP-driven webpages (Logon.php) that also want to display the header of the website using top.ssi. This code starts with:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head><title>Login to HVmusic</title>
    <?php
    virtual("/top.ssi");
    ...
```

Here is where the problem comes in. The `virtual("/top.ssi");` executes OK, but stops executing after it encounters the PHP file that is included in top.ssi `<!--#include virtual="/advertising/advertising.php" -->`. The output from advertising.php is displayed and then the PHP output from logon.php stops. So the output stops without even displaying the entire header.

If I remove the statement for `<!--#include virtual="/advertising/advertising.php" -->` then the logon.php displays it's page normally (without, or course, that bit of the header displayed by advertising.php). So this tells me that PHP is having a problem with a virtual() file that includes another PHP file.

Is there any way to fix this? Is it some known restriction in PHP? I've been googling for two days and can find no mention of this issue. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: You should probably rewrite this, so that it simply uses PHP’s `include` everywhere. There should be no need to involve two different technologies, if one of them alone is perfectly capable of doing what is needed on its own.

Comment: It's not really advisable to mix SSI and PHP. The `virtual()` call will trigger a second Apache and mod_php process, which isn't very efficient. Moreover it'll stop working with more current FCGI/FPM setups. Move to plain PHP `include()` statements if feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips, that clarified my thinking. I have just converted all my web pages to PHP and this solved the issue. Most of my pages were already PHP, so it wasn't much work to convert the HTML pages. All the include files I used were easily converted to use `<? php require "filename"; ?>` instead of `<!--#include virtual="filename" -->`

The underlying problem probably has to do with some conflict about running in PHP, then calling `virtual()` which calls an apache instance, which then calls another PHP instance to process the PHP include files I used.